# Removing value from array

Tags: collection, controllers, array

Need help trying to remove a array value (Customer ID) from a attribute array value in a collection

```
 //unfollowAction
 //Get Model to save data to.
 $model = Mage::getModel("userprofiles/userprofiles");
 $model->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('userprofiles_id', $id);
 $model->setUserprofilesId($id);

 //Get Model to fetch data from
 $model2 = Mage::getModel("userprofiles/userprofiles")->load($id);

 //Build Array output is 123,234,345,456,
 $FollowProfilesArray = array($model2->getFollowProfiles());

 //Remove specified ID from array, $profile_id equals current customer ID
 $remove_from_array = array_diff($FollowProfilesArray, array($profile_id,));

  foreach($remove_from_array as $key => $value){
  $select .= ''.$value.',';
  }

   //save new array to attribute value with the specified ID removed.
   $model->setFollowProfiles($select);
```

Problem is that this code is not removing the specified ID and saving the attribute value as **123,234,345,,**

Note:

*$model2->getFollowProfiles() output/saved value is 123,234,345,456 etc*

the code *$FollowProfilesArray = array($model2->getFollowProfiles());* does not work as stated above but if it hardcode the array data to

```
//Works,but not ideal or relevant
$FollowProfilesArray = array(123,234,345,456,);
```

So is there something im missing like exploding or imploding the **$FollowProfilesArray = array($model2->getFollowProfiles());** code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok sorted it out yeah. Code below.

---

*changed*

```
$FollowProfilesArray = array($model2->getFollowProfiles());
```

*to*

```
//explode out the attribute value
$FollowProfilesArray = explode(",","".$model2->getFollowProfiles()."");
```

---

*and changed*

```
foreach($remove_from_array as $key => $value){
$select .= ''.$value.',';}
```

*to*

```
    //so if $value is NULL save no value id, stoppped the adding of , to the attribute value

    foreach($remove_from_array as $key => $value){
    if($value == NULL) {
    //$select .= ''.$value.',';
    }else{
    $select .= ''.$value.',';           
    }
    }
```

---

so now on call to unfollowAction the specified ID is removed from the attribute value but keeps any other ID values.